# Camera2 sample app crashes on Lollipop device

Tags: android

I am trying to run Camera2 sample application https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic on Samsung SM-G900V (Galaxy S5) which is running Lollipop 5.0 API level 21.

However the application crashes - with following exception.

`android.camera2basic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method checkSelfPermission(Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Landroid/app/Activity; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.Activity' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)`

If I am reading google's documentation right API 21 should have support for Camera2 APIs.I have also tried same thing with Android emulator and getting similar crash. Is Camera2 API supposed to work on API21 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash doesn't have anything to do with the `camera2` package.

The problem is with the method you are calling to check runtime permissions: [the one you are using](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) was only added in API Level 23. 
[This article](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) provides methods to safely check runtime permissions on Android < 23, check the section titled

> Use Support Library to make code forward-compatible

Comment: @SubodhNijsure That because that method was also added in API 23: 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#setTorchMode(java.lang.String, boolean)

The whole sample may rely heavily on Android M / 23 methods although it declares the minSdk 21, so you'll have to figure out how to maouvre around those methods.

Comment: @SubodhNijsure: You may wish to keep track of [this issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/16), in hopes that perhaps Google can be convinced to fix their code.